# Flutter : TextFormField onchange value to Text widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Im new, I trying to do a onchange value while typing in text field, the value are updating the Text widget.

I tried two way, one is from onchanged , another is using TextEditingController, none of it working.

```
final txtController = TextEditingController();
String onchangeval = "";

TextFormField(
  onChanged: (value){
    onchangeval = value;
  },
  controller: txtController
),
Text("value_1 : " + onchangeval),
Text("value_2 : " + txtController.text),
```

NOTE : currently using extends HookWidget

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `setState`() which tells the framework that the widget’s state has changed and that the widget should be redrawn.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final txtController = TextEditingController();
  String onchangeval = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        TextFormField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                onchangeval = value;
              });
            },
            controller: txtController),
        Text("value_1 : " + onchangeval),
        Text("value_2 : " + txtController.text),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i using extends HookWidget , any idea to also use the setstate ?

Comment: @FeelRightz I suggest you to post another question and post your full code to be able to answer you correctly. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to put it in `setstate`.
documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

For making `setstate` working you have to change your widget type to a `StatefulWidget`

```
final txtController = TextEditingController();
String onchangeval = "";

TextFormField(
  onChanged: (value){
setState(() {
    onchangeval = value;
});
  },
  controller: txtController
),
Text("value_1 : " + onchangeval),
Text("value_2 : " + txtController.text),
```

Every time you want to make visual changes in your app you will have to work with states which can change.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `setState()`

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final txtController = TextEditingController();
  String onchangeval = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    onchangeval = value;
                  });
                },
                controller: txtController),
            Text(
              onchangeval,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Refer: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html

Comment: Hi, i using extends HookWidget , any idea to also use the setstate ?